# Tkinter show me results in a Text Box (as if it were print)

Tags: python, tkinter

I need some help, I think I'm getting confused all by myself.

I am trying to create a program that translates words or letters into other words. As code I did it perfectly:

```
import os
import re


Text = input("Text: ")
Text = Text.upper()

myDicc = {"AB": "Hello", "ET": "Beer", "OX": "Travel", "4BA2": "Car"}


for key, value in myDicc.items():
   Text = (re.sub(key, value, Text))
print(Text)
```

```
Texto: ET AB AB ET
Beer Hello Hello Beer

Process finished with exit code 0
```

So far so good, but now I'm trying to create a Tkinter to do it in program mode, and that's when I have the problem:

```
import os
import re
from tkinter import *

raiz = Tk()

raiz.title("Conversor Textos")
raiz.resizable(0, 0)

miFrame = Frame()
miFrame.pack(side="bottom")

Text1 = Text(miFrame, width=40, height=15, font=("Arial", 16))
Text1.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

Text2 = Text(miFrame, width=40, height=15, font=("Arial", 16))
Text2.config(state=DISABLED)
Text2.grid(row=4, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)

myDicc = {"AB": "Hello", "ET": "Beer", "OX": "Travel", "4BA2": "Car"}


def codButton():
    for key, value in myDicc.items():
        i = (re.sub(key, value, Text1.get("1.0")))
    Text2.insert("1.0", i)


TxtButton = Button(miFrame, text="Translate", command=codButton)
TxtButton.grid(row=5, column=1, pady=20)


raiz.mainloop()
```

I want the first code to be included in the Tkinter so that by entering the same words that I had in the Dictionary in Text Box 1, and then hitting the Translate button, they appear in Text Box 2 (but only in read mode). And if I delete and retype something else in Text Box 1 and retype a different word, the update will appear in Text Box 2. I don't know if I have explained myself correctly.

I hope you can help me to understand it because I am doing something wrong for sure. Thank you very much ^^

Comment: what is the problem? Do you get error message? Show it in question (not in comments) as text. Do you get wrong text? Show it in question. Don't expect that we will run code to see problem. Besides code may work correctly on our computers. And we can't read in your mind - you have to describe all details in question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three problems:

1. `DISABLE` doesn't allow to insert text - even using code. So you have to set it `NORMAL` before inserting

```
Text2.config(state=NORMAL)
Text2.insert("1.0", i)
Text2.config(state=DISABLED)
```

2. `get('1.0')` gives only first char - you need `get('1.0', 'end')`

**EDIT:** as @BryanOakley noticed in comment it should be `get('1.0', 'end-1c')` (minus 1 char) to skip extra newline which widget adds to text.

3. similar to first code you have to assign `re.sub()` to the same element to use it again in next loop - so you should first get text from widget, next use it in loop, and later put in other widget

```
    text = Text1.get('1.0', 'end')
    
    for key, value in myDicc.items():
        text = re.sub(key, value, text)
        
    print(text)
    Text2.config(state=NORMAL)
    Text2.insert("1.0", text)
    Text2.config(state=DISABLED)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Another problem: you may need `.delete('1.0', 'end')` to remove previous content because `insert()` doesn't remove it.

---

My version with few other changes:

```
import os
import re
import tkinter as  tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: all functions after imports (and classes) before main code 

def translate():  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for functions and variables
    
    text = text1.get('1.0', 'end')
    
    for key, value in my_dicc.items():
        text = re.sub(key, value, text)
        
    print(text)
    text2.config(state='normal')
    text2.delete('1.0', 'end')
    text2.insert('1.0', text)
    text2.config(state='disabled')

# --- main ---

# PEP8: `lower_case_names` for functions and variables

# - data -

my_dicc = {"AB": "Hello", "ET": "Beer", "OX": "Travel", "4BA2": "Car"}

# - gui -

root = tk.Tk()

root.title("Conversor Textos")
root.resizable(0, 0)

mi_frame = tk.Frame(root)  # it is good to use `parent` in all widgets
mi_frame.pack(side="bottom")

text1 = tk.Text(mi_frame, width=40, height=15, font=("Arial", 16))
text1.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

text2 = tk.Text(mi_frame, width=40, height=15, font=("Arial", 16))
text2.grid(row=4, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)
text2.config(state='disabled')

txt_button = tk.Button(mi_frame, text="Translate", command=translate)
txt_button.grid(row=5, column=1, pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

---

Comment: You are a Python wizard! Thank you so much, I couldn't see the bugs and didn't know what was going on, but your help is greatly appreciated! I have learned a lot by looking at your code, especially the bugs I was making and the ones I wasn't even putting in.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: `get('1.0', 'end')` should be `get('1.0', 'end-1c')` or else you'll get an extra newline that is added by the text widget.